Operator continuous with range in weak topology iff continuous with range in the norm topology
I'm self studying MacCluer's book Elementary Functional Analysis, and I came across the following problem.

Problem 3.18.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and suppose $T \colon X \to Y$ is linear.
Show that $T$ is continuous if $\varphi \circ T$ is continuous for all $\varphi$ in $X^*$.

Firstly, I think there is a typo in that the author meant $Y^*$ instead of $X^*$. One can then rephrase the problem as saying that $T$ is continuous with $Y$ having the norm topology if $T$ is continuous with $Y$ having the weak topology. (Note that the converse is straightforward, so we can also rephrase the problem as iff.)
But I was not able to prove the result unless I assumed Y is Banach. Assuming this, then we know that if $T$ is unbounded, then $TB_1$ is not bounded, where $B_1$ is the unit ball in $X$. Then one shows through the uniform boundedness principle that there will exist some $\varphi \in Y^*$ such that $\varphi(TB_1)$ is unbounded, completing the proof.
Is it true that we need $Y$ to be Banach, meaning that the author has made two typos in a single question? Also, what is the intuition for this result that two different topologies on $Y$ pick out the same set of continuous functions?

For every locally convex space, the weak topology has the same bounded sets.

Let's take a closer look at this application of the uniform boundedness principle. Recall the statement (taken from Wikipedia, lightly simplified):

Uniform Boundedness Principle — Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Y$ a normed vector space and $B(X,Y)$ the space of all continuous linear operators from $X$ into $Y$. Suppose that $F$ is a collection of continuous linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. If, for every $x\in X$,
$$\sup _{T\in F}\|T(x)\|_{Y}<\infty$$
then
$$\sup _{T\in F}\|T\|_{B(X,Y)}<\infty.$$

If $\varphi(TB_1)$ is bounded for all $\varphi \in Y^*$, then the space that Wikipedia refers to as $X$ is actually $Y^*$, and the collection $F$ is the functionals in $\widehat{TB_1}$, the embedding of $TB_1$ into $Y^{**}$. We know that, for all $\varphi \in Y^*$,
$$\sup_{\gamma \in \widehat{TB_1}} \gamma(\varphi) = \sup_{y \in TB_1} \varphi(y) < \infty.$$
Since $Y^*$ is the bounded linear maps to the Banach space $\Bbb{F}$ (where $\Bbb{F} = \Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ is the common field), $Y^*$ is itself complete (regardless of whether $Y$ is complete or not), so we conclude, by the UBP that
$$\sup_{y \in TB_1} \|y\| = \sup_{\gamma \in \widehat{TB_1}} \|\gamma\| < \infty,$$
and from here we naturally conclude that $TB_1$ is bounded, hence $T$ is continuous.
So, no, the completeness of $Y$ is not necessary.

Thanks! What about the second question: what is the intuition for this result that two different topologies on Y pick out the same set of continuous operators?
